# Reading a text file using php results in jarbeled mess

Tags: php, html

We have a program that exports an image as .bmp and creates an associated .txt file. Each file is generated incrementally  so that the first file set is named 0.bmp and 0.txt, second 1.bmp and 1.txt, etc. At present I'm using the following php code to open both the .bmp file as well as the .txt file.

```
        <?php 
    $dir = "Photos/Marshfield/*";  
    foreach(glob($dir) as $file)    
    {
        $ext = pathinfo($file);         
        switch($ext['extension'])
        {
            case "bmp":             
            echo "<img src=".$file.">";
            break;

            case "txt":
            $currentFile = file_get_contents($file);
            echo $currentFile;
            break;              
        }
    }       
    ?>
```

The problem is that the contents of the .txt file is random characters not the text that appears to be in the file. I guess I've hit a wall as to what is actually being read. Also is there a better way to effectively match up image/text pairs to ensure that they are associated correctly? At present I'm letting the browers  handle this as when the files  are created they are sequentially ordered and read as such.

Comment: Remember to use `break` in your case statements; and it should be a `:` after each case, not a `;`

Comment: Isn't your switch syntax broken?

Comment: Wow, I guess a second set of eyes, the break was the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `break` after each `case`, otherwise all code after matched `case` will execute. Also you have a typo after second `case` - there should be `:`. Try with:

```
<?php 
$dir = "Photos/Marshfield/*";  
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)    
{
    $ext = pathinfo($file);         
    switch($ext['extension'])
    {
        case "bmp":             
            echo "<img src=".$file.">";
            break;

        case "txt":
            $currentFile = file_get_contents($file);
            echo $currentFile;  
            break;            
    }
}       
?>
```

Please comment if it solves your problem.